# prepared statement fatal error non-object

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I got this query to insert a row in my table, but it gives this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in */misc/php/process.php on line 35

Code:

```
$query =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO pm     (van,naar,status,admin,onderwerp,tijd,bericht)   VALUES(:van,:naar,:status,:admin,:onderwerp,:tijd,:bericht)");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':van', $van); //<-- line 35
    $stmt->bindParam(':naar', $naar);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
    $stmt->bindParam(':admin', $admin);
    $stmt->bindParam(':onderwerp', $onderwerp);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tijd', $tijd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':bericht', $bericht);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've ever accepted an answer for your questions on SO. If you have helpful answers on your questions, choose the best one and mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, underneath the voting arrows. This will also award you some reputation points. If you haven't taken the tour, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Oh sorry, I had not taken the tour, I have now. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pm (van,naar,status,admin,onderwerp,tijd,bericht) VALUES(:van,:naar,:status,:admin,:onderwerp,:tijd,:bericht)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
```

This line:

```
$query =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO pm (van,naar,status,admin,onderwerp,tijd,bericht) VALUES(:van,:naar,:status,:admin,:onderwerp,:tijd,:bericht)");
```

is actually querying the database with that statement. It would make more sense as:

```
$result =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO pm (van,naar,status,admin,onderwerp,tijd,bericht) VALUES(:van,:naar,:status,:admin,:onderwerp,:tijd,:bericht)");
```

but you aren't looking for a result, but just a prepared statement, so follow my example above.